# Why returning an HTTP status 4** from an Express middleware causes an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing an Express middleware that checks the `Authorization` header to validate a bearer token. The token gets validated by another service, contacted through a `request-promise-native` call. The code is similar to the following:

```js
module.exports = function(options) {
  if (!options) {
    throw new Error("You must define at least an option")
  }

  // [...]

  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers) {
      if (req.headers.authorization) {
          const rpOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            uri: `${process.env.AUTH_SERVER_URL}/validate`,
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            form: {
              scope: scopes,
            },
            json: true,
          }

          rp(rpOptions)
            .then(data => {
              if (data.valid === true) {
                return next()
              }
            })
            .catch(e => {
              const { error, error_description } = e.error
              return res.status(e.statusCode).json({
                error: true,
                code: error,
                description: error_description,
              })
            })
        }
      }
    }

    res.status(401).json({
      error: true,
      description: "No bearer token found",
    })
  }
}
```

Then I have a jest test, where `egm` is the required middleware:

```js
beforeAll(done => {
  mockery.enable({
    warnOnReplace: false,
    warnOnUnregistered: false,
    useCleanCache: true,
  })

  mockery.registerMock("request-promise-native", () => {
    return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify({ valid: true }))
  })

  done()
})

it("throws an error if it cannot find the authorization header", done => {
  const app = express()

  app.use(
    egm({
      rules: {
        "/simple/rule": "scope1",
      },
    }),
  )

  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello world")
  })

  const server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => {
    request(
      {
        uri: "http://localhost:3000/",
      },
      (error, response, body) => {
        const result = JSON.parse(body)
        server.close()

        const { error: resError, code, description } = result
        expect(resError).toBeTruthy()
        expect(code).toBe("guard_error")
        expect(description).toBe("No bearer token found")
        done()
      },
    )
  })
})
```

In the test above I wanted to test that the response `No bearer token found` is sent to the client when the corresponding header is missing.
Jest is able to correctly `expect` the assertions above and to correctly stop Express, anyway I keep on getting this warning:

```
        at new StatusCodeError (.../express-guard-middleware/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
        at Request.plumbing.callback (.../express-guard-middleware/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
        at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (.../express-guard-middleware/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
        at Request.self.callback (.../express-guard-middleware/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
        at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at Request.<anonymous> (.../express-guard-middleware/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
        at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (.../express-guard-middleware/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)"
```

This doesn't happen when I use `200` as HTTP status inside my middleware, but I don't know how could I catch any exception since `res.status(401).json({})` isn't a Promise, so I cannot catch it. Any ideas on how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, despite I was requiring `request` module instead of `request-promise-native`, and despite the returned value wasn't a Promise, it seemed the code passed through a Promise.
So I ended to require `request-promise-native` in my test and wrapping it in a `try-catch` block and this time I didn't get any warning. I just had to add the middleware express for error handling and returning the desired response:

```js
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: true,
      code: "internal_error",
      description: err.message,
    })
  })
```